# How to store and retrieve RSA private key from a database table?

Tags: java, encryption

My application uses a private key to connect to SFTP using a keyfile.

When I test my code and reference a private key file stored on my computer, I can connect successfully.

The content of the keyfile has the following format.

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIICXAIBAAKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUp wmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ5 1s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQABAoGAFijko56+qGyN8M0RVyaRAXz++xTqHBLh 3tx4VgMtrQ+WEgCjhoTwo23KMBAuJGSYnRmoBZM3lMfTKevIkAidPExvYCdm5dYq3XToLkkLv5L2 pIIVOFMDG+KESnAFV7l2c+cnzRMW0+b6f8mR1CJzZuxVLL6Q02fvLi55/mbSYxECQQDeAw6fiIQX GukBI4eMZZt4nscy2o12KyYner3VpoeE+Np2q+Z3pvAMd/aNzQ/W9WaI+NRfcxUJrmfPwIGm63il AkEAxCL5HQb2bQr4ByorcMWm/hEP2MZzROV73yF41hPsRC9m66KrheO9HPTJuo3/9s5p+sqGxOlF L0NDt4SkosjgGwJAFklyR1uZ/wPJjj611cdBcztlPdqoxssQGnh85BzCj/u3WqBpE2vjvyyvyI5k X6zk7S0ljKtt2jny2+00VsBerQJBAJGC1Mg5Oydo5NwD6BiROrPxGo2bpTbu/fhrT8ebHkTz2epl U9VQQSQzY1oZMVX8i1m5WUTLPz2yLJIBQVdXqhMCQBGoiuSoSjafUhV7i1cEGpb88h5NBYZzWXGZ 37sJ5QsW+sJyoNde3xH8vdXhzU7eT82D6X/scw9RZz+/6rCJ4p0= -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I need to store the private key in a database table. When I attempt to retrieve the private key, I get the following exception:

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..) at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..) at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..) at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)

I would like to learn how to store the private key in the database table so that it would be retrievable.

EDIT: 
To clarify my question further. I would like to learn how to store the RSA private key in a database table so that I could retrieve the private RSA key back from the database without getting the IllegalBlockSizeException exception.

Comment: Your data needs to go as binary data

Comment: If you are on AWS then this approach is interesting http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx610S2MLVZWEA/Using-IAM-roles-to-distribute-non-AWS-credentials-to-your-EC2-instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you debug your code further - by a) trying to execute it with the key explicitly placed in the code as a String and making sure it works, then b) making sure that what you get back from the database is the same string you had originally. These steps would decouple the database logic part from the encryption logic part in your problem.

To get a more specific answer about the error you are getting one would probably need to see your code, though. So far it looks like you are trying to use the textual form of your key where a binary form is required. Or maybe you are messing up the base64 of the key when sending it to the db.